# Javascript rename property in 3D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a multidimentionnal array and i want to rename property recursevly, i've tried this function

```js
const newMenu =
        Array.isArray(copyMenu) &&
        copyMenu.length > 0 &&
        copyMenu.map(({ families: children, id: key, label: title, ...rest }) => ({
            key,
            title,
            ...rest,
            children,
        }));
```

But it rename just the big array, not the properties inside table property
This is my input array :

```js
const input = [
{
    id: 9040,
    label: "33",
    tables: [
      {
        id: 8957,
        label: "THB_Adresse_Famille",
        idFather: 8957,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 8941,
        label: "THB_Contact_Famille",
        idFather: 8941,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: [
          { id: 8947, label: "THB_Contact_Table", idFather: 8941 },
          { id: 9855, label: "THB_Contact_Table_BIS", idFather: 8941 }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 8949,
        label: "THB_Societe_Famille",
        idFather: 8949,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 8983,
        label: "THB_TELEPHONE",
        idFather: 8983,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 10070,
        label: "THB_TEST_5708",
        idFather: 10070,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      }
    ]
  },
   {
    id: 9761,
    label: "1111111",
    tables: [
      {
        id: 9742,
        label: "RRA PROTOCOLE",
        idFather: 9742,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 9753,
        label: "RRA TEST CASE LINE",
        idFather: 9753,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

The output should be ike this :

```js
const output = [
{
    key: 9040,
    title: "33",
    children: [
      {
        key: 8957,
        title: "THB_Adresse_Famille",
        idFather: 8957,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        children: []
      },
      {
        key: 8941,
        title: "THB_Contact_Famille",
        idFather: 8941,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        children: [
          { key: 8947, title: "THB_Contact_Table", idFather: 8941 },
          { key: 9855, title: "THB_Contact_Table_BIS", idFather: 8941 }
        ]
      },
      {
        key: 8949,
        title: "THB_Societe_Famille",
        idFather: 8949,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        children: []
      },
      {
        key: 8983,
        title: "THB_TELEPHONE",
        idFather: 8983,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        children: []
      },
      {
        key: 10070,
        title: "THB_TEST_5708",
        idFather: 10070,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    key: 9761,
    title: "1111111",
    children: [
      {
        key: 9742,
        title: "RRA PROTOCOLE",
        idFather: 9742,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        children: []
      },
      {
        key: 9753,
        title: "RRA TEST CASE LINE",
        idFather: 9753,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I'v searched on stackoverflow but i don't found any solutions to this case, any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: So, at all levels, `id` becomes `key`, `label` becomes `title` and `tables` becomes `children`, correct? This may be a proper use-case for recursion. Will work on an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursive approach to rename your keys by maintaining a lookup for renamed keys and recursively calling your function for array values.

```js
const input = [ { id: 9040, label: "33", tables: [ { id: 8957, label: "THB_Adresse_Famille", idFather: 8957, tableIsFamily: false, tables: [] }, { id: 8941, label: "THB_Contact_Famille", idFather: 8941, tableIsFamily: false, tables: [ { id: 8947, label:"THB_Contact_Table", idFather: 8941 }, { id: 9855, label: "THB_Contact_Table_BIS", idFather: 8941 } ] }, { id: 8949, label: "THB_Societe_Famille", idFather: 8949, tableIsFamily: false, tables: [] }, { id: 8983, label: "THB_TELEPHONE", idFather: 8983, tableIsFamily: false, tables: [] }, { id: 10070, label: "THB_TEST_5708", idFather: 10070, tableIsFamily: false, tables: [] } ] }, { id: 9761, label: "1111111", tables: [ { id: 9742, label: "RRA PROTOCOLE", idFather: 9742, tableIsFamily: false, tables: [] }, { id: 9753, label: "RRA TEST CASE LINE", idFather: 9753, tableIsFamily: false, tables: [] } ] }, ],
    keys = { id: 'key', label: 'title', tables: 'children'},
    rename = (arr) => {
      return arr.map(o => {
        return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(o).map(k => {
          const key = keys[k] || k;
          const value = Array.isArray(o[k]) ? rename(o[k]) : o[k];
          return [key, value];
        }));
      });
    };
console.log(rename(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your attempted solution is lacking the recursive call you say you want to implement. It may be a little tricky to conceive. You essentially need to **wrap the repeating code in a function**.

```
const recurse = (input) =>
  input?.map(({ tables, id, label, ...rest }) =>
    ({ children: recurse(tables), key: id, title: label, ...rest }))
```

Then, notice the **function calls itself** on the relevant part, a.k.a. the *general case*. Also not unimportantly, the function needs to know when to stop, i.e. when it has hit the *base case*. Without checking for the base case you will quickly find out where this website gets its name from. In the example above I did apply [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so it is a bit subtle.

Edit: with regard to [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), there are roughly two equivalent approaches (as far as I can see), here is the other which matches more with your initial approach:

```
const recurse = (input) =>
  input?.map(({ tables, id: key, label: title, ...rest }) =>
    ({ children: recurse(tables), key, title, ...rest }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a number of good answers have been provided. Here's one potential implementation to achieve the desired objective:

**Sample Code**

```
const replacePropsMap = {
  id: 'key',
  label: 'title',
  tables: 'children'
};

const renameProps = (arr = inputArr, propsMap = replacePropsMap) => (
  arr.reduce((fin, itm) => ([
    ...fin,
    {
      ...(
      Object.entries(itm).reduce((fin2, itm2) => ({
        ...fin2,
        ...(
          itm2[0] in propsMap
            ? { [propsMap[itm2[0]]]: itm2[1] }
            : {}
        )
      }), {})
      ),
      children: itm && itm.tables && itm.tables.length > 0
        ? renameProps(itm.tables)
        : []
    }
  ]), [])
);
```

**Explanation**

- Use `.reduce` to iterate through the array (with the aggregator as `fin` and each item as `itm`)
- Use `...` spread-operator to first place existing items (from past iterations)
- Next, for current `itm`, use `Object.entries()` and `.reduce` to filter-out `id`, `label`, `tables` props, but retain all other props
- Use `key`, `title` to hold values of `id`, `label` respectively
- Recurse the above for the `tables` array (if it exists) and store the result in `children` prop.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const inputArr = [{
    id: 9040,
    label: "33",
    tables: [
      {
        id: 8957,
        label: "THB_Adresse_Famille",
        idFather: 8957,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 8941,
        label: "THB_Contact_Famille",
        idFather: 8941,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: [
          { id: 8947, label: "THB_Contact_Table", idFather: 8941 },
          { id: 9855, label: "THB_Contact_Table_BIS", idFather: 8941 }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 8949,
        label: "THB_Societe_Famille",
        idFather: 8949,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 8983,
        label: "THB_TELEPHONE",
        idFather: 8983,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 10070,
        label: "THB_TEST_5708",
        idFather: 10070,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      }
    ]
  }, {
    id: 9761,
    label: "1111111",
    tables: [
      {
        id: 9742,
        label: "RRA PROTOCOLE",
        idFather: 9742,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 9753,
        label: "RRA TEST CASE LINE",
        idFather: 9753,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

const replacePropsMap = {
  id: 'key',
  label: 'title',
  tables: 'children'
};

const renameProps = (arr = inputArr) => (
    arr.reduce((fin, itm) => ([
    ...fin,
    {
        ...(
        Object.entries(itm).reduce((fin2, itm2) => ({
            ...fin2,
          ...(
            itm2[0] in replacePropsMap
                ? { [replacePropsMap[itm2[0]]]: itm2[1] }
              : {}
          )
        }), {})
      ),
      children: itm && itm.tables && itm.tables.length > 0
        ? renameProps(itm.tables)
        : []
    }
  ]), [])
);

console.log(renameProps());
```

Answer (score -1):

A potential solution could be:

```js
const input = [{
    id: 9040,
    label: "33",
    tables: [{
        id: 8957,
        label: "THB_Adresse_Famille",
        idFather: 8957,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 8941,
        label: "THB_Contact_Famille",
        idFather: 8941,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: [{
            id: 8947,
            label: "THB_Contact_Table",
            idFather: 8941
          },
          {
            id: 9855,
            label: "THB_Contact_Table_BIS",
            idFather: 8941
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 8949,
        label: "THB_Societe_Famille",
        idFather: 8949,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 8983,
        label: "THB_TELEPHONE",
        idFather: 8983,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 10070,
        label: "THB_TEST_5708",
        idFather: 10070,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 9761,
    label: "1111111",
    tables: [{
        id: 9742,
        label: "RRA PROTOCOLE",
        idFather: 9742,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      },
      {
        id: 9753,
        label: "RRA TEST CASE LINE",
        idFather: 9753,
        tableIsFamily: false,
        tables: []
      }
    ]
  },
];

function updateKeys(arr) {
  return arr.map(({
    tables,
    id: key,
    label: title,
    ...rest
  }) => {
    const children = Array.isArray(tables) && tables.length > 0 ? updateKeys(tables) : tables;
    return {
      key,
      title,
      children,
      ...rest
    }
  });
}

const output = updateKeys(input);

console.log(output);
```